# Correcting consecutive errors in time series

Tags: r, time-series, error-correction

I have very large continuous data sets (>1M rows) with frequent "breaks" or "jumps" due to sensor failure or other external factors. These breaks correspond to a constant value added or removed and last only for a limited amount of time. I am trying to realign these sequences with the rest of the data.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))

#simulating perfect dataset
dfe<-data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date('2015-07-12'),as.Date('2015-07-12')+49, by = '1 day'),
  valueideal=round(sin(seq(1,50,1))+20)
)

#introducing artifacts
dfe$valuer<-dfe$valueideal
dfe$valuer[10:20]<-dfe$valueideal[10:20]+10
dfe$valuer[30:35]<-dfe$valueideal[30:35]-10


#plotting ideal vs real data
plot(dfe$date, dfe$valuer, main="real data", ylim=c(8,32))
plot(dfe$date, dfe$valueideal, main="ideal data", ylim=c(8,32))
```

So my data look like the "real data" and I would like them to realign them to be like the "ideal data".
[image: Real vs Ideal corrected data]

So far I have made one `for` loop that mostly works except for the first data point of each artifact, and it slightly affects the rest of the data. I am not sure why or how to fix it:

```
#trying to solve it with a loop
dfe$valuel<-dfe$valuer
for (i in seq(2,length(dfe$valuel)-1,1)){
  future<-diff(c(dfe$valuel[i],dfe$valuel[i+1]))
  past<-diff(c(dfe$valuel[i-1],dfe$valuel[i]))

  if (abs(future)>2*abs(past)){
    dfe$valuel[i:length(dfe$valuel)]<-dfe$valuel[i:length(dfe$valuel)]-future

  }
}
plot(dfe$date, dfe$valuel, main="loop corrected data", ylim=c(8,32))
```

[image: Real data vs Loop corrected]

I am also worried to use this method on my very large dataset, I am not sure how long this will take. So I have also tried using this [R function to subtract the difference between consecutive values in vector from subsequent values in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391500/r-function-to-subtract-the-difference-between-consecutive-values-in-vector-from) method, but that didn't go well, possibly because it is hard to pick a `delta_max` value that is relevant:

```
#trying to solve it with a vectorised function
remove_artifacts <- function(weights, delta_max) {
  # calculate deltas, and set first delta to zero
  dw <- c(0, diff(x))
  # create vector of zeros and abs(observations) > delta_max
  # dw * (logical vector) results in either:
  # dw * 0 (if FALSE)
  # dw * 1 (if TRUE)
  dm <- dw * (abs(dw) > delta_max)
  # subtract the cumulative sum of observations > delta_max
  return(weights - cumsum(dm))
}
dfe$valuedm<-remove_artifacts(dfe$valuer, 10)
plot(dfe$date, dfe$valuedm, main="remove artifacts function", ylim=c(8,32))
```

[image: real vs de-artifact function]

So my question is, how can I efficiently correct these consecutive data breaks?

Comment: How do you know with certainty what the shift amount is?

Comment: @r2evans I don't, but I know my data points are very autocorrelated so I can assume that the value t(i+1)~= value at t(i). Then I can just approximate the shift to be the difference between an extreme value and the value at t(i-1). As long as every segment is shifted back by a constant it won't be an issue for my analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution that is fast as it uses [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and, therefore, modify in place. First, I setup the problem.

```r
#simulating perfect dataset
dfe<-data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date('2015-07-12'),as.Date('2015-07-12')+49, by = '1 day'),
  valueideal=round(sin(seq(1,50,1))+20)
)

#introducing artifacts
dfe$valuer<-dfe$valueideal
dfe$valuer[10:20]<-dfe$valueideal[10:20]+10
dfe$valuer[30:35]<-dfe$valueideal[30:35]-10
```

Next, I load [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and convert the data frame into a data table.

```r
# Load data.table
library(data.table)

# Convert data frame into data.table
setDT(dfe)
```

I calculate the difference in consecutive values using a vectorised approach, rather than the loop in the question.

```r
# Calculate changes
dfe[, delta := c(abs(diff(valuer)), 0)]
```

These differences are used to break the time series into intervals:

```r
# Labels intervals
dfe[, int := cut(.I, 
                 breaks = c(0, which(delta > 3 * sd(delta)/mean(delta)), nrow(dfe)), 
                 include.lowest = TRUE)]
```

I centre all intervals on zero.

```r
# Mean of zero
dfe[, value_new := valuer - mean(valuer), by = int]
```

Then, I add an offset taken as the mean of the first group.

```r
# Correct offset
dfe[, value_new := value_new + dfe[, mean(valuer), by = int][, first(V1)]]
```

Finally, I plot the result.

```r
# Plot result
with(dfe, plot(date, value_new, main="real data", ylim=c(8,32)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's an imperfect solution. First, I use your code to set up the problem.

```r
#simulating perfect dataset
dfe<-data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date('2015-07-12'),as.Date('2015-07-12')+49, by = '1 day'),
  valueideal=round(sin(seq(1,50,1))+20)
)

#introducing artifacts
dfe$valuer<-dfe$valueideal
dfe$valuer[10:20]<-dfe$valueideal[10:20]+10
dfe$valuer[30:35]<-dfe$valueideal[30:35]-10
```

Next, I use `breakpoints` from the `strucchange` package to find the breakpoints in the time series.

```r
# Find breakpoints
bp <- strucchange::breakpoints(valuer ~ date, data = dfe)

# Get breakpoints plus start & end of time series
int <- c(1, bp$breakpoints + 1, nrow(dfe))
```

Here, I add labels to the data set based on the breakpoints. I've plotted including the colour to see how well we did. (One straggler, which isn't too bad.)

```r
# Create labels
dfe$label <- cut(1:nrow(dfe), 
                 breaks = int, 
                 include.lowest = TRUE, 
                 right = FALSE)

# Plot "real" data coloured by label
with(dfe, plot(date, valuer, col = label, main="real data", ylim=c(8,32)))
```

[image]

I then switch to [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), because that's my jam.

```r
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dfe)
```

I group by `label` and then correct using the mean of each interval.

```r
# Offset by mean
dfe[, corrected := valuer - mean(valuer), by = label]

# Plot again
with(dfe, plot(date, corrected, col = label, main = "Corrected data", ylim = c(-10, 10)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

The straggler throws that interval off a bit, but the corrected solution isn't terrible.

---

### TL;DR

```r
# Find breakpoints
bp <- strucchange::breakpoints(valuer ~ date, data = dfe)$breakpoints

# Add start & end points
int <- c(1, bp + 1, nrow(dfe))

# Tag intervals
dfe$label <- cut(1:nrow(dfe), 
                 breaks = int, 
                 include.lowest = TRUE, 
                 right = FALSE)

# Correct by subtracting mean from each interval
data.table::setDT(dfe)[, corrected := valuer - mean(valuer), by = label]
```

Comment: Thanks this is an interesting approach but extremely slow for large datasets, so I cannot use it.

Comment: @Nakx I've added another fast solution.